# My Code does not want to output the extracted data

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to extract multiple links from a website (German yellow pages) but my code does nothing when I click the run button. My scraper does not react and gives no error warning. How can I fix it? Where is the problem?

I tried the code on the reddit frontpage, which works fine and I get a data output. But it does not succeed on the interested webpage https://www.gelbeseiten.de/arzt/heilbronn-neckar.

In this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knE4n.png) you can see what I want to extract.

In the div-tag with the id="gs_treffer" I want to extract from the article-tag the data-href link.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.gelbeseiten.de/arzt/heilbronn-neckar/"

#download the URL and extract the content to the variable html 
request = urllib.request.Request(url)
html = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()

#pass the HTML to Beautifulsoup.
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

#get the HTML of the table called site Table where all the links are                 displayed
main_table = soup.find("div",attrs={'id':'gs_treffer'})

#Now we go into main_table and get every a element in it which has a     class "title" 
links = main_table.find_all("article", class_="data-href")

#from each link extract the link 
#List to store a dict of the links we extracted

extracted_records = []
for link in links:
url = link['data-href']
record = {
    'url':url
    }
extracted_records.append(record)
print(extracted_records)
```

Comment: In general in such cases I propose to just `print()` the intermediate values you compute, just to understand which step has the first problem.

Comment: Thank you for your wise advice. I am totally new in this field. Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

You want to get rid off the *class_="data-href"* argument in find_all method, as "data-href" is not a class.

```
links = main_table.find_all("article")
```

I'm getting a list of dicts with urls now:

```
[{'url': 'https://www.gelbeseiten.de/gsbiz/b1f40122-810e-4e51-9915-0e5ac98e32a5'}, {'url': 'https://www.gelbeseiten.de/gsbiz/44beddcf-a428-452c-ade1-a2e4e7807b23'}, {'url': 'https://www.gelbeseiten.de/gsbiz/d3268940-07f3-41c4-bcbd-e33d341ba379'}, {'url': 'https://www.gelbeseiten.de/gsbiz/3fe695df-8695-4940-81f5-bee17fbdf168'}, {'url': 'https://www.gelbeseiten.de/gsbiz/f8a8f769-6806-4742-b62b-b46753bcebe0'}, {'url': 'https://www.gelbeseiten.de/gsbiz/aa19c150-da60-4ef6-ba00-ef672fbf34da'}, {'url': 'https://www.gelbeseiten.de/gsbiz/3e7b5aa8-7ae0-4779-a4ad-e2a51b4d7315'}, {'url': 'https://www.gelbeseiten.de/gsbiz/5d9e76b0-85ea-4316-88b2-b25f417b6d58'}, {'url': 'https://www.gelbeseiten.de/gsbiz/ca1d47eb-22e3-44bf-95de-0cf93f39761a'}, {'url': 'https://www.gelbeseiten.de/gsbiz/caf662da-d8ad-43b0-83c5-8b6c962195ba'}, {'url': 'https://www.gelbeseiten.de/gsbiz/346bf41b-e415-47cc-9609-788311322ab6'}, {'url': 'https://www.gelbeseiten.de/gsbiz/9f73cee9-a1dc-47b8-ab9e-e1855512cdc6'}, {'url': 'https://www.gelbeseiten.de/gsbiz/057ba124-aa45-40b9-a033-bf83ecc7c3ef'}, {'url': 'https://www.gelbeseiten.de/gsbiz/69b0e77e-9ae4-4f8f-82f7-9aa7cbab1a75'}, {'url': 'https://www.gelbeseiten.de/gsbiz/7a3de200-08c3-48ee-ac0c-fcfc183d35c3'}]
```

Comment: It works. Thank you very very much. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Your line `links = main_table.find_all("article", class_="data-href")` doesn't work. I think because you're not searching for an element based on its class.

If you replace that line with `links = main_table.find_all("article")` your script will work.

Comment: It works. Thank you very very much. Have a nice day